# Can we run Redis flush command for remote System from my local system?

Tags: redis

I wanted to run redis-cli flush all command from my local for UAT environment (ServerName), do not want to go again and again on that server and clear the cache as a dev.

do we have any command to connect that server to clear redis-cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this but be careful testing:

```
redis-cli -h SERVERNAME -p PORT flushall
```

Comment: yes the same command i tried, and it's work saved my effort for switching system. thanks @Setchell    

               `redis-cli -h SERVERNAME -p PORT`

and ran redis commands for flush